# Why don't public-beta sites show in my network profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, beta-sites

In my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3846032/scimonster?tab=accounts), my [Sports.SE account](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/6240/scimonster) doesn't show up.

I also added it to my "community list" in the site dropdown, yet it doesn't show my rep there either.

For [other users](https://stackexchange.com/users/3862816/yez?tab=accounts) (just one example, i'm lazy), Sports and other betas are in the network profile -- even at <200.

A [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51332/scimonster) account created at the same time doesn't show up either.

Update: I created a [scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/32466/scimonster) account in the past couple days, which immediately shows up in my network profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole "public beta" thing is just a red herring here.

When a user profile is created anywhere on the network, we insert a record into a table we use to speed up and simplify access to certain information (such as reputation, post count, and so on) across the network. Sometimes this process breaks down, and these records aren't created... which in turn means that stackexchange.com doesn't know that some of your profiles exist.

I fixed up the database records for your account, so you should see your network profile updated with accurate info now. The account list on your profile on any Q&A site is cached and will update on its own in a few. Let me know if it's still wrong in a day or two.

Comment: But real fix is adding something that will identify such cases and fix them e.g. scheduled task. No?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Naturally. I *think* this latest round of issues should already be resolved, but there may still be a few accounts that were left in this "borked" state.

Comment: So isn't there anything like the rep recalc for network accounts, making sure everything is synchronized?

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is. It works off of this table. :) Disclaimer: I'm not super well familiar with this part of our code/infrastructure. I'm kind of <s>making it up</s> learning as I go along here.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like there were a couple other accounts I created at the same time that didn't get inserted either.

Comment: @Scimonster Yeah, all told you were missing Super User, UX, Code Review, and Sports.